# Syntax for proper use of INDIRECT function using SUMIF in Openoffice spreadsheet to specify a functional range

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice

Similar to others who have asked related questions, I have a spreadsheet sheet which summarizes different expense categories on a different sheet (called PC activity)in the same file. PC activity is basically a running multiyear debit-credit-total ledger. The current SUMIF function which summarizes by category is hardcoded for a specific year. I would like to use (possibly ?) the INDIRECT function within this to reference a couple of cells which define the start and end rows of the functional SUMIF range. This would allow quick recalculation of different years without having to rewrite the formulas.

For example a current SUMIF function to summarize Bank charges is as follows:

=SUMIF($'PC Activity'.$F$39:$F$144;"Bank.*";$'PC Activity'.$C$39:$C$144)

This currently works fine. I have set up 2 cells in the current sheet, H1 and H2, whose values would replace the current hardcoded row references of 39 and 144 respectively.

What is the proper syntax to keep the sheet and column references static but just have a reference for the rows ?

I have tried:

=SUMIF(INDIRECT("$'PC Activity'.$F" & H1:"$F$" & H2);"Bank.*";INDIRECT("$'PC Activity'.$C$" & H1:"$C$" & H2))

but this returns a 502 error.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, with double quotes moved to include the colon, and a second & added after the H1s:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("$'PC Activity'.$F" & H1 & ":$F$" & H2);"Bank.*";INDIRECT("$'PC Activity'.$C$" & H1 & ":$C$" & H2))
```